# How to update multiple records data through alv reports in SAP ABAP?

Tags: abap

How to update multiple records data through ALV REPORT IN SAP ABAP?

Comment: Please describe in detail what you're trying, give us a case / scenario what you want to achive.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Selected Lines, I used to do that task ... If you are going to update random fields, the easiest way to do this is to delete all the data in database and insert it with the new updates .. 
for an other solution you need to use the gd-edit functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Loop statement with your logic inside to change/update only certain values/fields.

Answer (score 0):

try this....
Use for all entries in select statement and pass updated work area to FM reuse_alv_grid_display.